# How do I query nested with normal match query together?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I want to fire nestedQuery on **addresses** and multiMatchQuery on **name** in single query. I tried few ways but I am getting **"[bool] query does not support [nested]"**. I don't know whether this is possible or not (ES version: 7.x).

When I separately querying (i.e.nestedQuery() & multiMatchQuery()) that time it is working fine.
Please help me with that.
This is the mapping I am using:

```
{
  "employee" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "addresses" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "properties" : {
            "permanentAddress" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "TemporaryAddress" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "id" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}



1.    {
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "addresses",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                { "match": { "addresses.permanentAddress": "xxx" } }
          
              ]
            }
          },
          "score_mode": "avg"
        }
      }
    }
    
2.    {
     "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must" : [
              {
                "multi_match" : {
                  "query" : "xxx",
                  "fields" : [
                    "name^1.0"
                  ],
                  "type" : "best_fields",
                  "boost" : 1.0
                }
              }
            ]
        }
      }
    }
```

1. nestedQuery() = looking for **xxx** value in addresses.permanentAddress
2. multi_match() = looking for **xxx** value in name

If value of **name or addresses.permanentAddress** matches with **xxx** then returns the result.

Comment: can you please share the queries which you want to combine ?

Comment: Thanks for the response ESCoder,
BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders
                .multiMatchQuery("xxx", name));
        
QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery( "addresses.permanentAddress", "xxx"));
NestedQueryBuilder nestedQuery = QueryBuilders
  .nestedQuery("addresses", query, ScoreMode.None).innerHit(new InnerHitBuilder());
BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().filter(nestedQuery);

Comment: Sorry for the format @ESCoder . In avobe comment  I have provided the java api and in the description I have added those queries .Actually these two queries should be with (operator.or), it checks for multiMatchQuery() or nestedQuery()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  "bool" : {
"should" : [
  {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [
        {
          "match" : {
            "name" : {
              "query" : "xxx",
              "operator" : "AND",
              "prefix_length" : 0,
              "max_expansions" : 50,
              "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
              "lenient" : false,
              "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
              "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
              "boost" : 1.0
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
      "boost" : 1.0
    }
  },
  {
    "nested" : {
      "query" : {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : [
            {
              "match" : {
                "employee.permanentAddress" : {
                  "query" : "xxx",
                  "operator" : "AND",
                  "prefix_length" : 0,
                  "max_expansions" : 50,
                  "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
                  "lenient" : false,
                  "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
                  "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
                  "boost" : 1.0
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      },
      "path" : "employee",
      "ignore_unmapped" : false,
      "score_mode" : "none",
      "boost" : 1.0,
    }
  }
],
"adjust_pure_negative" : true,
"boost" : 1.0
```

}

This Bool query with nested worked for me and with that I can able to check parent's as well as nested property.